# Plotting saw-tooth functions with varying heights

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, function

I am preparing a note on example of an everywhere continuous nowhere differentiable function. The construction involves a saw-tooth function, viz., `h` in the following way:
[image]

I want to plot the following functions, say on the domain `[-1,1]`.

1. `h(x)`
2. `h_1(x)`
3. `h_2(x)`
4. `h_3(x)`
5. `h(x)+h_1(x)`
6. `h(x)+h_1(x)+h_2(x)`
7. `h(x)+h_1(x)+h_2(x)+h_3(x)`

I am trying to define and plot the function `h` in `tikz`. Because that way, it would be easiest for me to do the rest. That is where I am getting stuck. Following MWE summarises my effort:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize, scale=3,%
            declare function={h(\x) = (\x>= {floor(\x)}, \x<= {floor(\x)+1/2})*(\x-floor(\x)) +
                and 
                (\x> {floor(\x)+1/2}, \x<= {floor(\x)+1})*(1-\x+floor(\x));}
            ]
            \draw plot[domain=-5:5] (\x,{h(\x)});
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I define `h` so that it can calculate `h(x)` for any real value of `x`? Any help will be appreciated. A copy of the graphs done in Desmos [can be found here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qzk1rasnqo).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is the van der Waerdens function you want to draw (or rather the construction of it).

In general for such graphics, I do not think you need to define the function on the whole line, but it is sufficient to have a working variant on the interval [-1,1], and draw it shifted if necessary.

In a recent analysis book project we used `h(x) = abs(x - round(x))`, that in fact does work for all real x. I guess you can use that in tikz as well.

In any case, the book I wrote was in ConTeXt, and the figures are done in MetaPost/MetaFun, so that is how the example is done below.

```
\starttext
\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
u:=3cm ;

def vdwbas(expr x) = abs(x-round x) enddef ;

def vdw(expr n,x) =
  if n = 0:
    vdwbas(x)
  else:
    vdwbas(x*pow(4,n))/pow(4,n)
  fi
enddef ;

path xaxis, yaxis ;
xaxis = ((-1.1,0)--(1.1,0)) scaled u ;
yaxis = ((0,-0.1)--(0,0.6)) scaled u ;

drawarrow xaxis withpen pencircle scaled 0.25 ;
drawarrow yaxis withpen pencircle scaled 0.25 ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden0}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(0,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden1}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(1,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden2}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(2,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden3}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(3,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden01}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(1,x)+vdw(0,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden012}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(2,x)+vdw(1,x)+vdw(0,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{vanderwaerden0123}
\includeMPgraphic{vanderwaerdenbas}
draw function(1,"x","vdw(3,x)+vdw(2,x)+vdw(1,x)+vdw(0,x)",epsed(-1),epsed(1),1/1000) scaled u ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startplacefigure[reference=fig:vdw]
\startcombination[nx=2,ny=4]
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden0}}   {(a)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden0}}   {(b)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden1}}   {(c)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden01}}  {(d)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden2}}   {(e)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden012}} {(f)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden3}}   {(g)}
{\useMPgraphic{vanderwaerden0123}}{(h)}
\stopcombination
\stopplacefigure
\stoptext
```

[image: van der Waerden]

Comment: The line `h(x) = abs(x - round(x))` has done the trick! However, unfortunately the rest of the script is not for LuaTeX, what I am using for the entire note. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: As mentioned, the rest is not for LaTeX indeed, but for ConTeXt (on luatex or luametatex). I included it since I thought the answer would be more complete with an example (and maybe someone will be helped of it at some point), but the main part of the answer is indeed the formula for h. I'm glad it helped you.